# Blazor Server App - need to use Google reCaptch with checkbox

Tags: .net-core, blazor-server-side

I have been struggling for a few days now trying to get Google reCaptcha (version 2 using the checkbox) working in a Blazor Server app using .NET 6 framework.  I thought this would be a fairly simple implementation, but I have not found a working example.  There is one example I found here [Using Google reCaptcha with Blazor](https://github.com/sample-by-jsakamoto/Blazor-UseGoogleReCAPTCHA) that has has a WASM and Server example but using .NET Core3.1.  I ran the project but the Server example compiles but does not work as the WASM does.  Also the code is very complicated mapping a TS file to a JS file.
Does anyone have a simple working example or can point me in the direction of finding one?   This has just been a frustrating few days.  I love Blazor, but did not think this was so hard to do.  I am sure I am missing something.

Thanks for any help.